# htaccess and forward one url to another

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stagingsite.com/site/mobile [R=301]
RewriteRule ^faq/$ /mobile/faq
```

The first line is working correctly. If the user is on an iphone then redirect to the mobile directory where the index page is displayed.

I also want users visiting:

http://stagingsite.com/site/faq

to get forwarded to http://stagingsite.com/site/mobile/faq if they're on an iphone but the last line of code above doesn't seem to be achieving this.

Any ideas what I have wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` directives only get applied to the *immediately following `RewriteRule`. So you have the condition that checks for **iPhone**, but that only gets applied to the redirect rule, and not the faq rule. You have to duplicate it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stagingsite.com/site/mobile [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^faq/?$ /site/mobile/faq [L]
```

You should also include `L` flags so the 2 rules don't accidentally interfere with each other. And your regex and target needs to be updated to accept an optional trailing slash and the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

taking out the slash before mobile as

```
RewriteRule ^faq/$ mobile/faq
```

works?